# Using Columns in a Dashboard

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS to develop reports that will be displayed as a dashboard using the Microsoft Report Control within a web page.

On the dashboard I want to show key information about students within a class and I am setting my report up to use columns on the page i.e.

```
Student 1            Student 2            Student 3            Student 4
Student 5            Student 6            Student 7            Student 8
```

However, the report only displays in this way when it is rendered to PDF, word etc.  Is there a method I can use that will allow the page to be rendered correctly within the web control?

Comment: What does it look like in the web control?

Comment: It shows it as one long list and ignores the columns

Comment: Screen shot please.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, I have had to use 3 tables as columns doesn't work on a report control in a website.

Thanks for the suggestions :)